# Set charset in ErrorDocument messages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, utf-8, apache2.4

I have an `.htaccess` file that looks like this:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddCharset utf-8 .html
Order Allow,Deny 
ErrorDocument 403 "Error 403 - Esta ubicación no es pública"
```

The file itself is encoded as UTF-8. However, Apache insists on declaring ISO-8859-1 and the error message is mangled:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2013 10:06:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6
Content-Length: 42
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

If I manually change encoding to UTF-8 in my browser text looks correct.

Site has been granted all permissions:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tmp
    DocumentRoot "D:/tmp"

    <Directory "D:/tmp">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

... and there's nothing relevant in Apache logs.

What bit am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Terrific question!! I must say. I had to dig all my resources and read lot of manuals to find the reason for this behavior.

It appears to be a known behavior but not very well covered in official manuals. Finally, I found one reference of it in [**`this Apache manual`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html#suppress-error-charset):

> ### suppress-error-charset
>
> *Available in versions after 2.0.54*
>
> When Apache issues a redirect in response to a client request, the
>   response includes some actual text to be displayed in case the client
>   can't (or doesn't) automatically follow the redirection. Apache
>   ordinarily labels this text according to the character set which it
>   uses, which is ISO-8859-1.
>
> However, if the redirection is to a page that uses a different
>   character set, some broken browser versions will try to use the
>   character set from the redirection text rather than the actual page.
>   This can result in Greek, for instance, being incorrectly rendered.
>
> **Setting this environment variable causes Apache to omit the character
>   set for the redirection text**, and these broken browsers will then
>   correctly use that of the destination page.

And that is exactly the behavior you're seeing that `charset=iso-8859-1` is coming in the headers.

---

### How to fix:

Have your .htaccess code like this:

```
# set desired env variable to suppress iso-8859-1 charset
SetEnvIf Host ^ suppress-error-charset

# set desired 403 message with desired charset 
ErrorDocument 403 "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'></head><body>Error 403 - Esta ubicación no es pública</body></html>"
```

Please note that **`SetEnvIf Host ^`** is a condition that will always hold true hence **`suppress-error-charset`** will always be set. I have tested just with those 2 lines in my `.htaccess` and got correct error message displayed in my browser.

Comment: Setting `suppress-error-charset` makes Apache omit the `charset` parameter in `Content-Type` (which is definitively better than sending an incorrect one). I guess there's no way to send the correct one but using meta tags (or relying in browser's auto-detect) seems to be a reasonable workaround. Nice answer :)

Comment: Exactly and this particular thing appears to me a bug rather than a feature. How can it enforce `ISO-8859-1` blindly? Later on somebody realized it and introduced `suppress-error-charset` to suppress character encoding altogether. Better fix would have been to allow whatever character encoding in this env variable.

Comment: Thanks, thats my solution 10 years later ... Are ther other ways meanwhile?